# HelmDeploy@0 task does not resolve variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a problem with the Azure Pipelines, whose behaviour during deployment I cannot explain at the moment.

I have two pipeline yaml's. azure-pipeline-api.yml and azure-pipeline-client.yml for the same AzureRepo which contains a Api and a Client.

There are two branches, one is **main** and the other is **dev**. I would like the pipelines to use different variables in the Helm deployments depending on the branch.

However, I have the problem that no one of the HelmDeployment gets variables. Although both pipelines are written identically. We can be sure that the variables passed to the stage are all filled and correct. (I wrote the job ReadVariable to check this).

API:

```
trigger:
  - main
  - dev

pool:
  name: test-pool

stages:
  - stage: Api
    jobs:
      - job: DefineVariables
        displayName: Define Variables
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Set env variables
            name: EnvVariables
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                PACKAGE_VERSION_API=$(xmlstarlet select --template -value-of /Project/PropertyGroup/Version --nl "TestProject/TestProjectApi.csproj")
                if [ $(Build.SourceBranch) == "refs/heads/main" ]
                then
                  IS_PROD=true
                  API_VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION_API
                  SERVICE_CONNECTION=aws-prod
                  SERVICE_NAMESPACE=test-prod
                  DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API=devops/deployments/api/prod-values.yaml
                else
                  IS_PROD=false
                  API_VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION_API-dev
                  SERVICE_CONNECTION=aws-dev
                  SERVICE_NAMESPACE=test-dev
                  DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API=devops/deployments/api/dev-values.yaml
                fi
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IS_PROD;isOutput=true;]$IS_PROD"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=API_VERSION;isOutput=true;]$API_VERSION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_CONNECTION;isOutput=true;]$SERVICE_CONNECTION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_NAMESPACE;isOutput=true;]$SERVICE_NAMESPACE"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API;isOutput=true;]$DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API"
                echo Build.Reason: $(Build.Reason)
                echo Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
                echo IS_PROD: $IS_PROD
                echo API_VERSION: $API_VERSION
                echo SERVICE_CONNECTION: $SERVICE_CONNECTION
                echo SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $SERVICE_NAMESPACE
                echo DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API
      - job: ReadVariable
        dependsOn: ["DefineVariables"]
        displayName: Read env variables
        variables:
          API_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.API_VERSION'] ]
          IS_PROD: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.IS_PROD'] ]
          SERVICE_CONNECTION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_CONNECTION'] ]
          SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_NAMESPACE'] ]
          DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API'] ]
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                echo Build.Reason: $(Build.Reason)
                echo Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
                echo IS_PROD: $(IS_PROD)
                echo API_VERSION: $(API_VERSION)
                echo SERVICE_CONNECTION: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
                echo SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $(SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
                echo DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $(DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API)
      - job: BuildApi
        dependsOn: ["DefineVariables"]
        variables:
          API_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.API_VERSION'] ]
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: "Api - Build and Push Docker Image"
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: "dockerregistry.implico.com"
              repository: "devops/test-api"
              command: "buildAndPush"
              Dockerfile: "TestProject/Dockerfile"
              tags: $(API_VERSION)
      - job: DeployApi
        dependsOn: BuildApi
        variables:
          API_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.API_VERSION'] ]
          IS_PROD: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.IS_PROD'] ]
          SERVICE_CONNECTION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_CONNECTION'] ]
          SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_NAMESPACE'] ]
          DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API'] ]
        steps:
          - task: HelmDeploy@0
            displayName: "Deploy Api"
            inputs:
              connectionType: "Kubernetes Service Connection"
              kubernetesServiceConnection: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
              namespace: $(SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
              command: "upgrade"
              chartType: "FilePath"
              chartPath: "devops/deployments/api"
              releaseName: "test-api"
              overrideValues: image.tag=$(API_VERSION)
              valueFile: $(DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API)
```

and Client:

```
trigger:
  - main
  - dev

pool:
  name: test-pool

stages:
  - stage: Client
    jobs:
      - job: DefineVariables
        displayName: Define Variables
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Set env variables
            name: EnvVariables
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                PACKAGE_VERSION_CLIENT=$(awk '/version/{gsub(/("|",)/,"",$2);print $2}' ./TestProject/package.json)
                if [ $(Build.SourceBranch) == "refs/heads/main" ]
                then
                  IS_PROD=true
                  CLIENT_VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION_CLIENT
                  SERVICE_CONNECTION=aws-prod
                  SERVICE_NAMESPACE=test-prod
                  DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT=devops/deployments/client/prod-values.yaml
                else
                  IS_PROD=false
                  CLIENT_VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION_CLIENT-dev
                  SERVICE_CONNECTION=aws-dev
                  SERVICE_NAMESPACE=test-dev
                  DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT="devops/deployments/client/dev-values.yaml"
                fi
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IS_PROD;isOutput=true;]$IS_PROD"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CLIENT_VERSION;isOutput=true;]$CLIENT_VERSION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_CONNECTION;isOutput=true;]$SERVICE_CONNECTION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_NAMESPACE;isOutput=true;]$SERVICE_NAMESPACE"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT;isOutput=true;]$DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT"
                echo Build.Reason: $(Build.Reason)
                echo Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
                echo IS_PROD: $IS_PROD
                echo CLIENT_VERSION: $CLIENT_VERSION
                echo SERVICE_CONNECTION: $SERVICE_CONNECTION
                echo SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $SERVICE_NAMESPACE
                echo DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT: $DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT
      - job: ReadVariable
        dependsOn: ["DefineVariables"]
        displayName: Read env variables
        variables:
          CLIENT_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.CLIENT_VERSION'] ]
          IS_PROD: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.IS_PROD'] ]
          SERVICE_CONNECTION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_CONNECTION'] ]
          SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_NAMESPACE'] ]
          DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT'] ]
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                echo Build.Reason: $(Build.Reason)
                echo Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
                echo IS_PROD: $(IS_PROD)
                echo CLIENT_VERSION: $(CLIENT_VERSION)
                echo SERVICE_CONNECTION: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
                echo SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $(SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
                echo DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT: $(DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT)
      - job: BuildClient
        displayName: Build Client
        dependsOn: ["DefineVariables"]
        variables:
          CLIENT_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.CLIENT_VERSION'] ]
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: "Client - Build and Push Docker Image"
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: "dockerregistry.implico.com"
              repository: "devops/test-client"
              command: "buildAndPush"
              Dockerfile: "TestProjectClient/Dockerfile"
              tags: $(CLIENT_VERSION)
      - job: DeployClientDev
        displayName: Deploy Client
        dependsOn: BuildClient
        variables:
          CLIENT_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.CLIENT_VERSION'] ]
          IS_PROD: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.IS_PROD'] ]
          SERVICE_CONNECTION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_CONNECTION'] ]
          SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_NAMESPACE'] ]
          DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT'] ]
        steps:
          - task: HelmDeploy@0
            displayName: "Deploy Client"
            inputs:
              connectionType: "Kubernetes Service Connection"
              kubernetesServiceConnection: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
              namespace: $(SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
              command: "upgrade"
              chartType: "FilePath"
              chartPath: "devops/deployments/client"
              releaseName: "test-client"
              overrideValues: image.tag=$(CLIENT_VERSION)
              valueFile: $(DEPLOYMENT_FILE_CLIENT)
```

For some reason, the variables in the "ReadVariable" and "BuildClient/BuildAPI" jobs are resolved correctly, but not in DeployClient and DeployApi. I don't really understand why. Does anyone have an idea if this is due to the "HelmDeploy@0" and why this is?

Here you can see that the image tag is missing but I can assure you that the other variables are not resolved either.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify dependencies to pass the variables between the affected jobs. In your scenario please add another dependency `dependsOn: DefineVariables` for the **Deploy** jobs:

```
  - job: DeployApi
    dependsOn: 
    - DefineVariables
    - BuildApi
```

API for example:

```
trigger:
  - main
  - dev

pool:
  name: test-pool

stages:
  - stage: Api
    jobs:
      - job: DefineVariables
        displayName: Define Variables
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Set env variables
            name: EnvVariables
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                PACKAGE_VERSION_API=$(xmlstarlet select --template -value-of /Project/PropertyGroup/Version --nl "TestProject/TestProjectApi.csproj")
                if [ $(Build.SourceBranch) == "refs/heads/main" ]
                then
                  IS_PROD=true
                  API_VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION_API
                  SERVICE_CONNECTION=aws-prod
                  SERVICE_NAMESPACE=test-prod
                  DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API=devops/deployments/api/prod-values.yaml
                else
                  IS_PROD=false
                  API_VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION_API-dev
                  SERVICE_CONNECTION=aws-dev
                  SERVICE_NAMESPACE=test-dev
                  DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API=devops/deployments/api/dev-values.yaml
                fi
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IS_PROD;isOutput=true;]$IS_PROD"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=API_VERSION;isOutput=true;]$API_VERSION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_CONNECTION;isOutput=true;]$SERVICE_CONNECTION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_NAMESPACE;isOutput=true;]$SERVICE_NAMESPACE"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API;isOutput=true;]$DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API"
                echo Build.Reason: $(Build.Reason)
                echo Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
                echo IS_PROD: $IS_PROD
                echo API_VERSION: $API_VERSION
                echo SERVICE_CONNECTION: $SERVICE_CONNECTION
                echo SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $SERVICE_NAMESPACE
                echo DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API
      - job: ReadVariable
        dependsOn: ["DefineVariables"]
        displayName: Read env variables
        variables:
          API_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.API_VERSION'] ]
          IS_PROD: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.IS_PROD'] ]
          SERVICE_CONNECTION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_CONNECTION'] ]
          SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_NAMESPACE'] ]
          DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API'] ]
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                echo Build.Reason: $(Build.Reason)
                echo Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
                echo IS_PROD: $(IS_PROD)
                echo API_VERSION: $(API_VERSION)
                echo SERVICE_CONNECTION: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
                echo SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $(SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
                echo DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $(DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API)
      - job: BuildApi
        dependsOn: ["DefineVariables"]
        variables:
          API_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.API_VERSION'] ]
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: "Api - Build and Push Docker Image"
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: "dockerregistry.implico.com"
              repository: "devops/test-api"
              command: "buildAndPush"
              Dockerfile: "TestProject/Dockerfile"
              tags: $(API_VERSION)
      - job: DeployApi
        dependsOn: 
        - DefineVariables
        - BuildApi
        variables:
          API_VERSION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.API_VERSION'] ]
          IS_PROD: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.IS_PROD'] ]
          SERVICE_CONNECTION: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_CONNECTION'] ]
          SERVICE_NAMESPACE: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.SERVICE_NAMESPACE'] ]
          DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API: $[ dependencies.DefineVariables.outputs['EnvVariables.DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API'] ]
        steps:
          - task: HelmDeploy@0
            displayName: "Deploy Api"
            inputs:
              connectionType: "Kubernetes Service Connection"
              kubernetesServiceConnection: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
              namespace: $(SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
              command: "upgrade"
              chartType: "FilePath"
              chartPath: "devops/deployments/api"
              releaseName: "test-api"
              overrideValues: image.tag=$(API_VERSION)
              valueFile: $(DEPLOYMENT_FILE_API)
```